# Creating a JQuery menu popup

Tags: jquery, css

Can anyone tell me how the best way to create this menu popup with the below images?

[image]

The next image shows what it should look like when you hover over the more link.
I have the popup menu as an image.

[image]

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    $(function() {
        $(this).find('#more_ddown').hide();
    });

    $(function() {
        $('#v3NavHeaderLink3').hover(function(){                    
            $('#more_ddown').fadeIn('fast');                        
            }, function(){
                $('#more_ddown').hide();
            });
        });

</script>

    <nav id="NavHeader">
        <a href="#" title="" id="Link1">Link #1</a>
        <a href="#" title="" id="Link2">Link #2</a>
        <a href="#" title="" id="Link3">More</a>
        <img src="img/more.png" id="more_ddown" alt="alt" />    
    </nav>
```

Comment: Could you post the code you have so far please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML

```
<ul id="menu">
    ...
    <li id="moreButton">MORE</li>
</ul>

<div id="morePopup">
   <div id="heading"><img src="arrow.png"/></div>
    <ul>
       <li><a href="#">link 1</a>
       <li><a href="#">link 1</a>
       <li><a href="#">link 1</a>
   </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#morePopup
{
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  left:/*whatever you want*/
  top:/*whatever you want*/
  width:/*whatever you want*/
  height:/*whatever you want*/
}
#heading
{
  display:block;
  width:/*same as morePopup*/
  height:/*whatever you want*/
}
```

*/ [this is for rounded corners](http://perishablepress.com/press/2008/11/24/perfect-rounded-corners-with-css/)   too long to put here

JQUERY

```
$("#moreButton").bind('mouseover',function(){
              $('#morePopup').css('display','block');
});
$("#morePopup").bind('mouseout',function(){
        $(this).css('display','none');
});
```

Comment: That is the idea.  The css and html may not be 100% accurate, but its in the right direction

Comment: the hover does not seem to work and when I move away from the link how do I keep the dropdown still visible? cheers

Comment: yeah you can use the blur show hide. As far as the move away do this...
$("#moreButton").bind('mouseover',function(){
              $('#morePopup').css('display','block');
});
$("#moreButton").bind('mouseout',function(){
        $("#morePopup").css('display','none');
});

Comment: I just edited the post as well.  Let me know if that works.  :)

Comment: used the jquery 'mouseover' and 'mouseleave' funtions in the end.